# How do hide the toolbar in Finder by default?

Tags: macos, finder, toolbar

I can hide the toolbar in Finder by pressing option+command+T. However it only saves this to the .DS_store file in the folder I do press the command. I'd like to have the toolbar hidden as default, as I only use shortcuts anyway and I like the extra viewing space it gives.

Comment: Take a look at [this thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1087286). I don't know any other way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any way to hide the toolbar by default, but you could drag all items out of it after selecting Customize Toolbar from the context menu.

[image]

Or run something like this in AppleScript Editor:

```
tell application "Finder"
    repeat with f in (get folders of home)
        open f
        tell window 1
            set toolbar visible to false
            close
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: How did you remove the icons?

Comment: You can hide them in the view options in column view. There's a bug where the icons are still shown when Arrange By is not set to None or Name though.

Comment: dragging out all the items still leaves a weird patch of empty toolbar. The second solution worked well for me though :)

Answer (score 0):

FinderMinder is a great product which can intercept Finder windows when they are opened and adjust them to any setting you wish.  It basically runs an AppleScript that performs the Finder window adjustments just as the window is opening.

The net effect is that you can trim the Finder window button clutter by setting the side bar to invisible, the tool bar to invisible and anything else you wish to hide.

The only gotcha is that you have to drill down into the apps's 'Package' and edit the AppleScript by hand. The edit is very simple though, changing "true" to "false" or visa versa.

[FinderMinder](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/labs/) -> http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/labs/

how it works: https://vimeo.com/72299758

This is not an ad, I have no stake in the company or the product. The product simply saved my sanity with the ever so devolving / mutating Finder.